# dock folders - how to view list/grid/fan on hover & open in finder with 1-click

Tags: dock, folders

I feel that its slowing my productivity, to have to click on the dock folders to see the list of contents.

Are there any apps or tweaks that will enable me to view the contents automatically when hovering the mouse over the folder.

I would also like to be able to 'open in finder' in 1-click, instead of the 2-step's of clicking on the folder, then selecting 'open in finder'

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any way to view the contents of a folder when hovering the mouse over it.

To open a folder without having to click then click "Open in Finder", you can Option-Command click on the folder and it will open the folder in Finder. (Another tidbit: Command click on the folder and it will open its enclosing folder in Finder)

Answer (score 0):

Your Post describes hovering over a dock icon to see contents of the folder... but this happens by default... if you are referring to the Finder then... In High-Sierra or higher MacOS:

1. Open `System Preferences` > `Accessibility` > `Mouse & Trackpad`
2. Click(tick) `"Spring Loading Delay"` and use the slider to sent delay length.

Comment: "but this happens by default" -> please explain this more because it does not happen automatically for me. Hovering over a dock folder does nothing. You have to click it to open it.

Comment: Did you try the setting i described... Make sure you have some delay set... 100ms or something.  If it is set to 0, then it turns off entirely and you have to click on the folder icons